# How to covert curl Authorization Token to Ajax code

Tags: ajax, curl

I have a working curl code.

`curl https://customr.heliumdev.com/api/v1/customers/6590401996 --header "Authorization: Token token="XXX""`

And I want to use Ajax to achieve this code, my code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://customr.heliumdev.com/api/v1/customers/6590401996",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"XXX\""); 
            },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(){
              alert("Cannot get data");
            }
        });
```

But I got error said that

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://customr.heliumdev.com/api/v1/customers/6590401996. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://3c4527.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I tried `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"XXX\"")`, `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token token=XXX")`, and `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token token='XXX'")` . All of these gave me same error.

Could anyone help me to covert curl to ajax ?

Comment: In short, you can't with JavaScript alone. Not unless you own the third-party resource and can provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It's a browser security violation to process an ajax request on a third party domain when the header is not present, which is why you're getting the error. My advice is to ajax to your server and have your server make the curl request since it is not bound by the same security context rules. See [this CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) article for more information...

Comment: My website is hosted on Shopify so basically I don't have my own server, is there any other methods I can use to solve this problem?